# How to verify session and engine objects are able to connect

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

The lines below declare the `engine` and `session` objects.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker
URL = 'mysql://root:pass@12.34.56.78/mydb'
engine = create_engine(URL, echo=False)
session = scoped_session(sessionmaker()) 
session.remove()
session.configure(bind=engine, autoflush=False, expire_on_commit=False)
```

I would like to know how `engine` and `session` objects could be used to check if they are able to connect to the database with URL, database name and credentials provided.

Comment: You could issue a dummy select, for example `engine.execute('SELECT 1').fetchall()` or the like, and catch any exceptions raised.

Comment: If you look at the sqlalchemy engine structure it looks like url and credentials are checking by `DBAPI`.    `create_engine()` function produces an Engine object based on a URL. http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/engines.html#engine-configuration